# Why does jsx code formatting not correctly

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

`vscode` is my favorite editor, I have a code formatting problem with it. Here is my `jsx` code:

```js
return <div className={panelHeadingClassName}>
    <h3 className={style.panelTitle}>
        <i className={iconStyle[iconClass]}></i>
        {title}
        <small className={style.panelSubTitle}>{subTitle}</small>
    </h3>
</div>
```

when I use <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to format it, it gives me this:

```
return <div className = {
  panelHeadingClassName
} >
<
h3 className = {
  style.panelTitle
} >
<
i className = {
  iconStyle[iconClass]
} > < /i> {
  title
} <
small className = {
  style.panelSubTitle
} > {
  subTitle
} < /small> <
/h3> <
/div>
```

Obviously, it's not correct.

`vscode` version - `v1.10.2`, and not install any code formatting extension.

So, **I don't want to install any code formatting extension, is there any config for `vscode` to doing this correctly?**

-- update --

Sorry about that. I check my extensions installed, found `Beautify` extension. But why the i use vscode code formatting, it use `Beautify`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As you note, the Beautify extension is the root cause here (see [this issue](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/issues/116)). That extension provides a document formatter that VSCode will run when you run the format command

A few options:

- Disable the extension
- Disable Beautify for just js files by removing the `js` entry from the `"beautify.language"` setting
- Make sure your file has a language mode of `javascriptreact`. I believe this will prevent Beautify from running on the file

Comment: yeah. thanks. I disable the extension. I think the code formatter of VSCode is good enough.

Comment: Make sure your file has a language mode of `javascriptreact`. This help me

Answer (score 38):

Choose the language in right-bottom corner as "JavaScript React".

And a better way is to rename the `js` files to `jsx`.

Answer (score 26):

For those using both `.js` and `.jsx`, this is how I resolved it.

Go to settings in VSCode, search and open the `settings.json` file.

Make sure you have both:

```json
    "[javascript]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
```

Same thing for TypeScript as well. Make sure you have both `typescript` and `typescriptreact` enable like above.

Comment: I had installed `Prettier - Code formatter` and though VS Code will pick up it as default formatter ? Isn't that the case or is it bug with VS Code ?

Answer (score 15):

Install Prettier (if not installed), and try to add this your user or workplace settings:

```
"prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true
```

Do not put linebreak between return and the returned JSX expression. Trigger autoformat (Alt+Shift+F), and check if works.

Answer (score 10):

This is because vs code is recognising the language of `.js` files as "JavaScript" not "JavaScript React" and beautify uses the language that vs code says it is to decide how to format it.

As suggested by other answers, you could manually select the language (in the bottom right corner of vs code) as "JavaScript React" or rename each file extension to `.jsx` but what I think is easier is to add:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact",
}
```

into my **workspace** `settings.json` file.

Now vs code will automatically recognise all `.js` files language as "JavaScript React" in the workspace!

If your unsure how to get to this file, check this out [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

**Edit:**
This is useful if all the `.js` files in your workspace are "JavaScript React"!

Comment: very well explained. Thanks, it works for me.

Answer (score 6):

You need to choose the default formatter.

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+P(Win) or Cmd+Shift+P(Mac)
2. Type Format Document With...
3. Then click Configure Default Formatter... and choose it from the list.

[image]

Comment: I had installed `Prettier - Code formatter` and though VS Code will pick up it as default formatter ? Isn't that the case or is it bug with VS Code ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Beautify and the workaround that you should do, you can use instead [rc-beautify vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atom.rc-beautify). Install it, CTRL+B to format JS, JSX code.

Answer (score 0):

You did not wrote your file name, if it is an ".js" file, rename to ".jsx"

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control over the formatting, prettier also allows that.
Create a file with the name `.prettierrc` (dot prettierrc) in the root of your project and add the configuration as required.
For example, add the following JSON in the `.prettierrc` file:

```
{
 "singleQuote": true,
 "trailingComma": "none"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Install **Prettier - Code formatter** extension.
2. Open Settings from bottom left corner. 
   Perform below steps in both **User** as well as **Workspace** tab:
3. Search **React Snippets > Settings: Prettier**, then

   - Enable the check-box for **React Snippets > Settings: Prettier Enabled** option
   - (optional) Select **Prettier - Code formatter** from the dropdown of **Editor: Default Formatter**
     [Prettier - Code formatter setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNWoU.png)

Now restart your VS Code and you should get results as expected.

****If it's still not resolved perform below step as well**:
4. In settings (User tab only), search **Emmet: Include Languages**, click on *Add Item* and add **javascript** and **javascriptreact** under *Item* and *Value* columns respectively and click *OK*.
[Emmet: Include Languages setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrpQA.png)

Answer (score 0):

For those who have problems with Format On Save instead of using Ctrl+Shift+P (Win) or Cmd+Shift+P (Mac), just make sure to check **Format On Save**:

File > preferences > setting > text editor > formatting, and then check "Format On Save."