# How to prevent visual studio code from putting line breaks in my JSX?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, formatting, jsx

I'm trying to set up my visual studio code to clean up or beautify my JSX/JS when coding in React.

I have several prettier formatting plugins installed. When I do 'Format Document', it makes my code look horrible. 
[image]

Something nice like this:

```
  <Map
    style={{
      height: "100%",
      width: "100%",
      margin: "0 auto"
    }}
    center={position}
    zoom={10}>
```

turns into junk like this...

```
return ( <
            Map style = {
                {
                    height: "100%",
                    width: "100%",
                    margin: "0 auto"
                }
            }
            center = {
                position
            }
            zoom = {
                10
            } >
            <
```

I've searched through many settings files...what is controlling this? I turned on `Prettier: Jsx Bracket Same Line` to be true. I set the character width to be wide. I turned off any line break things. I honestly have no idea why it's making my jsx look horribly unreadable. When I drop this same code into https://prettier.io/playground, it looks fine coming out.

What setting is putting my code onto separate lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920590/vscode-jsx-code-formatting-not-correct  see that link for some tips

Comment: @DvidSilva That solved it. Do I close this question or answer it?

Comment: you can close it probs. or mark as answered. or add an edit/comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vscode - jsx code formatting not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920590/vscode-jsx-code-formatting-not-correct)

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by changing the **Select Language Mode** from *JavaScript* to *Javascript React* in your **Visual Studio code editor**