# Why is VSCode Prettier is taking my divs apart?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Prettier in Visual Studio Code. 
I am using JSX, and when i vrite `<div>`, Prettier disolves it into 2 lines, like this

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = "App" >

      <
      /div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can i prevent it?

Comment: Can you create an empty file and just put the div there? See if prettier breaks it too.

Comment: I have disabled Prettier, but it still happens !? I tried both .js and .jsx estension. Changed nothing.

Comment: I have found temporary solution. in settings.json deleted this row: "editor. formatOnSave": true, but this is not permanent solution, because I cannot use Prettier.

Comment: Is this similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920590/why-does-jsx-code-formatting-not-correctly

Comment: Yes, it is, but there is no solution there.

Comment: They found out that the extension "Beautify" was causing the issue. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I didn't understand that thread well. I have Beautify installed. I disabled it. I think this should work. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jsx code formatting not correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920590/why-does-jsx-code-formatting-not-correctly)