# Why VS Code Formatter damage my JSX codes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formatting, jsx

I'm getting the error in the below image

[image: ac]

I used 2 VSCode plugins [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) and [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify)

both made the same error

unfortunately , it's too late to undo my changes

related issues
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920590/why-does-jsx-code-formatting-not-correctly)
[2](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/issues/132)

I tried to implement the answers , but no solution worked for me

what now ? my file includes many lines , can't trace it line by line

Comment: Please share your code for AnimatedComponent.

Comment: @jmargolisvt my codes not include this AnimatedComponent - it maybe a plugin I use , my file is advertise.js , it fired this error , after formating the codes inside it

Comment: Does this happen when you disable all extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I face this all the time. It seems to be a bug with Prettier.

A quick fix is to reload the Window.

1. Press `Cmd + P`(On Mac) / `Ctrl + P`(On Windows).
2. Type `> Reload`
3. Select `Developer: Reload Window`

That seems to fix it.

But it happens again, every now and then.

**PS:** I hope you're using Version Control.

Comment: Unfortunately , it did not work and I am not using Version Control

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. By it would work, I meant that it won't damage your code again for some time. I didn't mean that it would magically fix the broken code.

Comment: can I share my file codes with you , if you can returning it to the correct format :(

Comment: Sure. I can try. But no guarantees. Also, you should make a note to self, **ALWAYS USE VERSION CONTROL**. :)