# VS Code Scatters Next JS Files

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js

I am learning NextJS right now but I can't seem to proceed, as anytime I make a change and hit `CTRL + S`
The codes become scattered. See screenshots below to better understand my plight:

**Before Save**
[image]

**After Hitting Save**
[image]

Please, how can I fix this? I am using VS Code version `1.53.2`

Comment: It should be a `jsx` file, not a `js` file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jsx code formatting not correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920590/why-does-jsx-code-formatting-not-correctly)

Comment: install a "real" formatter, like `prettier`, rather than relying on built in formatting, and set it to auto-apply on save?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your js files into jsx extension. Example: `index.js` to `index.jsx` and save the file.